# What does this CSS value mean?

Tags: css, css-position

While viewing the source of a web page, I came across this CSS, applied to a span within a button:

```
.whatever button span {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1e+7px;
}
```

What does `left: -1e+7px;` mean? Is this some trick I should be aware of?

Comment: That looks like scientific notation. If I really want to get rid of something -4000px or something works just fine.

Comment: But why not just change the 'visibility' or 'display' property?

Comment: To trick page spiders. A lot of them will ignore buttons that are invisible, but still do things if the button is off the screen, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific%5Fnotation) (in this case, for -10,000,000px). To the best of my knowledge, CSS does not allow scientific notation (it is absent from [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#numbers), but a Google search for ["css scientific notation"](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+scientific+notation) turns up several complaints against Batik — an SVG engine — for **not** supporting it). I would guess that some CSS parsers do support such notation, despite it not being part of the standard, but if so, I cannot find information on *which* parsers support it.

To be safe, I would avoid using it in your own stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

From the CSS2 spec on Numbers

---

Some value types may have integer values (denoted by ~integer~) or real number values (denoted by ~number~). Real numbers and integers are specified in decimal notation only. An ~integer~ consists of one or more digits "0" to "9". A ~number~ can either be an ~integer~, or it can be zero or more digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more digits. Both integers and real numbers may be preceded by a "-" or "+" to indicate the sign. -0 is equivalent to 0 and is not a negative number.

---

IE accepts scientific notation. Firefox ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

Does CSS support scientific notation?  Are they trying to put the button ten million pixels off to the side, maybe to have a default button that's not visible?

Answer (score 0):

This is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), meaning -1*10^7 = -10000000.

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid CSS, according to the [W3C validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/):

```
.whatever button span    Value Error : position attempt to find a semi-colon before the property name. add it
.whatever button span    Value Error : left Unknown dimension 1e
```

If you add the missing `;` after `position: absolute`, you still get:

```
whatever button span     Value Error : left Unknown dimension 1e
```