# What does this CSS property mean : text-indent: -1e+7px;

Tags: css

Any body can explain this CSS property please?

`text-indent: -1e+7px;`

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means -1 times 10 to the power of 7, or -10 000 000. Effectively hiding the text out of the view by moving it 10 million pixels off the screen. As David Dorward noted, this might be the result of some automated tools' number conversion error but could also been done manually as a shorthand for a huge number.

Comment: +1, nice addition would be to point out this is scientific notation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Comment: @schnaader: Yes, it's called scientific notation, but strangely, I don't recall ever seeing that notation in a scientific paper (at least in mathematics or computer science)… it seems more used by engineers. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It often works, but is not part of the standard, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921835/what-does-this-css-value-mean

Answer (score 6):

[text-indent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#indentation-prop) alters the start position of the first line of text in a block. The value is an error (CSS doesn't accept [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)), probably generated by an automated tool that was given a huge value.